# TFX AutoML on local System

Tags: local, automl, kubeflow, tfx

Is it possible to perform AutoML using TFX on local environment. I know with kubeflow and GCP we can perform AutoML on the cloud, but I want to do all of these steps locally and deploy the model to a local directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [example notebook](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/template_local) to setup TFX with local orchestrator. Also, you can also use [interactive notebook](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/components_keras) to run TFX pipeline using interactive orchestrator on Google Colab notebook.

Thank you!